# Compiling gRPC examples for QNX

Tags: grpc, qnx

Successfully compiled gRPC for QNX and now trying to build the examples.

Build command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=qcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=q++ ../..
```

Linker errors:

```
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable greeter_client
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable greeter_async_client
[100%] Linking CXX executable greeter_async_server
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -ldl
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -ldl
/home/csa/src/qnx//host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -ldl
```

I found the following link, looks like it might be cmake issue for -lpthread, but not sure about -ldl.
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21579

Answer (score 0):

library pthread of QNX is in libc
https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/p/pthread_create.html